# Background image issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a background image, but it does not display when checking in the browser, and nothing is shown. I am compiling the .scss into a **CSS folder**.

Here I attach an image of my folders.
[image: Folders root]

Here is how I am writing it with the *background* property:

```css
.graphic-design {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  // background: yellowgreen;
  margin-top: -8vh;
  background-image: url('./images/mobile/image-graphic-design.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: The path is relative to the css-file. so `../images/mobile/image-graphic-design.jpg`  (double dots) probably works better (but maybe there is some other issue as well!)

Comment: (A good way to catch those is to open the network-tab in your browser dev-tools and filter by 404 errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
background-image: url('../images/mobile/image-graphic-design.jpg');
```

Use `../` to go up one level and then go to images folder.

If you want to read more about file path in css, you can read [this](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) article.

Answer (score 1):

This must be an issue with the path. You can debug yourself. Check Your Developer tools (F12)

Go to Application Tab and load your application / Page again.

You will be able to see if your image is successfully loaded from the path. You may see 404 error here Check the URL path and adjust the code to set the correct path.

[image]